# How does minecraft autosaves and keeps proccesing the game at the same time?

Tags: java, c++, iostream, save

Ok guys. I know you can read files and the sort by (at least in C++) using ostream and istream. My question is that the game >Minecraft< is able to generate chunks (the game world), save them and load them when needed all while the player is interacting with the game. By interacting I mean building, mining, walking, dying (quiet frequently).
How is all of this possible?? How can you modified date that's being saved every 2 seconds?? Should I open a stream and not close it, or is there a special function or method that does this??
Thanks!!

Comment: I am guessing the entire world is a monte-carlo simulation, with a noisefunction generating the world/content, you just need to take a snapshot of the function in that case.

Comment: @arynaq - that is basically how the initial state of the world is generated, but the player does things to change the world (mining, building, killing cows, picking flowers, ...) and so on, and that state needs to be saved.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know specifically how Minecraft does it, but you could get consistent snapshots in real-time in a variety of ways.  For example.

- The data structures could create a shadow copy of the relevant part of a data structure if the mutator tries to change it during a snapshot.
- All nodes could be locked to prevent the mutator changing them while a snapshot is in progress.  If the mutator attempts to acquire a lock on a node, this could cause the snapshot process to move the node to the front of the queue ... so that the mutator only gets blocked for a short time.
- They may simply have implemented the snapshot creation process to be incremental, and the typical increments could be quick enough that the user generally does not notice that the mutator pauses for a short period.  (My guess is that anything less than 1/10th of a second is going to be unnoticeable ... unless it generates an obvious "visual artifact".  Even then, Minecraft's rendering quality is such that users would probably not be unduly worried anyway.  At least, that's what I observe from watch other people playing ...)

---

But one thing is for sure.  The implementation is likely to be very Minecraft specific and hand-tuned.  There's no generic Java library class that magically does this kind of thing.  I doubt that they are using the Java equivalent of IOStreams to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Minecraft or Java specifically, but the usual method is to use a memory mapped file:

- The program asks the operating system to map a file into memory. In C the relevant functions are [`mmap`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) (on Unix) and `CreateFileMapping` (Windows).
- The program now has a block of memory it can access **as if** the file was entirely read into memory, even though it wasn't. The operating system will load the relevant data from the file on disk as needed.
- Any changes the program makes to the block of memory will be written to disk. The OS will usually cache these changes and only write them to disk if the cache is full or the disk or CPU is idle.

Comment: OMG!! Thanks. The "CreateFileMapping" was just what I was looking for. It saves a file in virtual memory and then you can read and write to the file directly.